# LibTorch and OpenCV Libs not working in same cmakelist file

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, pytorch, libtorch

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Detect)
#set(Torch "/home/somnath/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "CVINCLUDE: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Detect main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Detect  ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}; ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

${TORCH_LIBRARIES}; ${OpenCV_LIBS} both are not working at the same time if want to use to build the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjfdO.png)

Comment: Please, elaborate "not working": what is happened, what error do you get, etc.

Comment: attached screenshot is the error for not able link library of opencv

Comment: No, do not use screenshots for error messages and code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. Instead, copy paste the error message into the question post as **text**. See also [ask].

Comment: Hi @Pixolish did you solve the issue,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake linking error, finding library but "undefined reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456607/cmake-linking-error-finding-library-but-undefined-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the libTorch from Pre-cxx11 ABI to cxx11 ABI

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

All thanks to Jacob HM from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459156/13045595

Answer (score -1):

I had face the same problem. Spent 20+hrs to change CMake file and what not...But there is nothing to do with CMakeLIsts.txt
..Just comment "using namespace cv" if you have in your code...It worked for me.
Hope it solves your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the error you see they are using the fully qualified name (`cv::foo`), so `using namespace cv` wouldn't help.